SSH Broken Pipe when running resource intensive program on the server (even with throttled CPU)
I am running large language models on an Orange Pi 5 Pro running Ubuntu 22 server (client is running Ubuntu 24). It has 8 cores, and after running the LLM for a short amount of time it consistently drops the SSH connection. When I throttle cpu with cpulimit --limit=100 the connection will stay open, but if I use a value of 200 it will drop. The device has 8 cores, so --limit 200 should only be using 2 cores, and leave 6 cores for other processes which is plenty of processing power for SSH and other system processes. Adding keep alive values as suggested in other "broken pipe" threads did not work. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to fix this, or why it is happening?

Does it only drop the SSH connection? Does the program remain running on the server? Does uptime -p keep increasing or does it reset to zero? Have you checked whether the system logs say anything at all when this happens?

thank you, checking uptime was helpful. I solved the issue, my power supply was not strong enough, when I switched to a better one it worked fine.

In my case, the power supply on my machine was not strong enough. After switching from the USB port on my desktop to a power strip I no longer had issues.
